# vim netrw directory listing windows to linux

Tags: ssh, vim, putty

On a Windows box, using gVim.

I use Kitty a Putty clone for ssh, the command line commands are identical except for the names.

At work I contact many Linux servers from my Mac using MacVim.  Netrw works great, I am using an ssh key that is present on my remote Linux boxes.

My most common use case is:

```
:e sftp://user@host/subdir/
```

This would get me a listing of the contents of a sub directory below my home directory called subdir.  From there I can descend till I find the file I want to edit.

So at home I have a Windows box (Windows 10 fully up to date).
gVim 8.1.1779 a very recent version.

Using scp or sftp works great for editing a file if I know the exact name. My .vimrc for this is:

```
let g:netrw_sftp_cmd= 'c:\Kitty\kscp.exe -agent -batch -q -sftp'
let g:netrw_scp_cmd= 'c:\Kitty\kscp.exe -agent -q -batch'
```

-agent tells it to use kageant (pageant) to be an agent for my ssh key.

As I said I have no problems getting to a file that I know the exact path to.   But if I try to do my common use pattern to get a directory listing it fails.

My limited understanding of netrw and what little help googling had provided to me is setting:

```
let g:netrw_list_cmd = 'c:\Kitty\klink -T -ssh -agent -batch'
```

which fails miserably to get me any results.  I have tried many ways to get that and failed.  Most of the articles I find both here and on Google are 10 years old and no longer valid.

So I tried writing scripts that I put into netrw_list_cmd, but it does not pass the user@host portion to my script.

Is this problem solved anywhere?  Am I the only one who uses directory listing with netrw remotely? and uses ssh keys?

Thanx

Bodger

Comment: Oh if I do not do the netrw config options, it asks for my password on each operation which is painful.

Answer (score 1):

Alrighty, things have certainly changed over the years.

Putty is no longer necessary, there is an OpenSSH client already built into Windows 10.

- The first thing I did was add my id_rsa to c:/User/[username]/.ssh
- Install OpenSSH client if you already do not have it installed,
  plenty of online articles to show you how
- I have Windows 10 Pro so ssh-agent.exe does not run automagically
- Goto task manager Services
- OpenSSH Authentication Agent Properties Automatic (delayed start) not
  sure about delayed but I read articles.
- Now start up cmd.
- ssh-add C:/Users/[user]/.ssh/id_rsa
- Remove any let g:netrw commands from .vimrc And it all works now.
- I wish someone had said that before